# CSS: Bootstrap Gallery gaps in col-sm-4 image-col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create a image gallery

```
'<a href="../'.$img.'" class="col-sm-4 image-col"  data-gallery>';
'<img src="../'.$img.'" class="img-responsive">';
'<figcaption>';
$desc;
'</figcaption>';
'</a>';
```

For some reason there are gaps when the gallery is processed.
I'm grabbing the data from a for loop and there should be no gaps.
All the images are the same height.

See below for better view

[image]

Comment: provide fiddle or link of your site so can see html and css.

Comment: https://seek.estate/buy/4-300-rise-of-an-empire#gallery

Comment: images are inside the anchor tag [class col-sm-2] and anchor tag have width 16% .. make it width :auto so it will wrap the image inside and this will remove the space.

Comment: Gallery images are inside the anchor tags like this - <a href="https://seek.estate/imdb/stills/tt12538632.jpg" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 image-col" style="width:auto;" data-gallery="">
            <img src="https://seek.estate/imdb/stills/tt12538632.thumb.jpg" data-num="2" data-original="https://seek.estate/imdb/stills/tt12538632.jpg" alt="Still of 300: Rise of an Empire" class="img-responsive pull-left thumb lightbox">
          </a>   And here anchor tag have css of width 16% which actually more then the images width thats why its showing the space.

Comment: Yes you are adding the - margin remove this(for trial comment it) --.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

Comment: ok working now I set  '<img src="../'.$img.'" class="img-responsive" style="width:auto;" >';